# Should different questions with same answers be marked duplicate?

Tags: discussion

A couple of days ago, I came across a question that would result in the same answer with another question, but they both were different.

This question had the answer: [Will my married life suffer or my husband die because of this wish?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61511/will-my-married-life-suffer-or-my-husband-die-because-of-this-wish)

But this question was the one asked: [What if you wished to take someone else's misery?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62215/what-if-you-wished-to-take-someone-elses-misery)

I believe this is considered duplicate since then we would be writing out the same answer one more time. If someone asks a question like this well they could have easily found the answer to it they searched just a bit more like the keywords: 'wish' or something.

*And recently we have been getting too many wish and cursing type of questions* I wonder what that's all about.

Comment: In many cases that I have observed, unregistered users open a new account (unregistered account) to ask their questions again or spam the site. Others ask a question and never come back, either because they've asked on many more sites or because they lost the focus etc.. Generaly it is not possible to mark duplicate questions as such unless one of them has a(n) (up)voted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible and appropriate when the other question has an (up-voted or accepted) answer that answers the first question you'd like to mark as duplicate:

> Duplicate of... - the fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. There’s more information in our duplicate questions help center article.
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. ([Help-Center on closed questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions))

Not all duplicates must/should be closed:

> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. This does not mean that every duplicate will immediately be closed; we love (some) dupes. There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way. ([Help-Center on duplicates](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates))

Sometimes a new question or answer is better/shorter etc. formulated.
Nevertheless one could consider marking them as duplicate to interlink between different questions and answers.

Comment: Okay! Jazāk Allāhu Khayran. For taking your time on writing such a great answer! wa-Alaikumussalam.